# Exposing authenticated data from Azure Mobile App via an ASP.NET MVC 5 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to access authenticated data from [Mobile apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-value-prop-preview/) via Asp.Net MVC5.
The backend is .NET (not Node.JS) and I'm using the C# SDK (not Javascript). Since custom auth (user\pwd) is not yet available for Mobile Apps I'm trying to connect with Facebook.

I've found [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2013/06/25/exposing-authenticated-data-from-azure-mobile-services-via-an-asp-net-mvc-application.aspx)  but is very outdated now.

Comment: Can you provide more detail on the issues you are having? That post from Carlos is still very relevant. Once you have the user logged into your MVC app using FB, you can use that token to get an Azure Mobile token. Then you'd need to hold onto the Azure Mobile token so you can create the user object on the request anytime you create a new Azure Mobile client.

Comment: The problem is that mvc5 site and mobile service have differents URL, so I need to configure 2 Fb application, that would return 2 different tokens..

Comment: No, you should only need the one FB application for your MVC application. The user isn't going to be using the Azure Mobile login function directly, so they won't need the redirect for that.Unless that is, you are going to have BOTH the MVC app and FB login to the mobile app directly. Then it might be more setup on the FB side.

Comment: Mobile users (xamarin forms app) do need to authenticate via FB. I want the same users to be able to connect to the MVC using FB and see their data consuming the Mobile App Service. So actually there are 2 Url (MVC and Mobile App Service)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to do both a mobile app clients AND the MVC client, then you might need to specify a list of OAuth URLS that are valid per:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security#surfacearea

You can set the list of valid callback URLs on the settings -> Advanced tab in the facebook app management.

Comment: I'll take a look and let you know. Meanwhile, I market your answer as useful. I'll update it after I test it. Thanks